# Static values get mangled

Tags: smart-contract

if you run the following (on eosio v1.8.4):

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>

namespace eosio {
    class UTL {
        public:
        static name code;
        static symbol sym;
    };  

    class [[eosio::contract("static")]] dapp : public contract {
        public:

        dapp(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds) 
            : eosio::contract(receiver, code, ds) {
            UTL::code = code;
            print("\nconstructor(I): code=", UTL::code);
            UTL::sym = symbol("XX", 2); 
            print("\nconstructor(II): code=", UTL::code);
        }   

        [[eosio::action]]
        void tst() {
            print("\ntst(): code=", UTL::code, ", sym=", UTL::sym);
        }   
    };  
}
```

you'll see that as soon as the second static variable gets set, the first one gets messed up.  is this a problem with the EOS compiler, or am I doing something boneheaded?

**Appendix I**

thinking that perhaps having a single variable within the class would help I tried this, which fails in the same manner:

```
    class UTL {
        public:
        static struct {
            name code;
            symbol sym;
        } conf;
    };  

    class [[eosio::contract("static")]] dapp : public contract {
        public:

        dapp(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds) 
            : eosio::contract(receiver, code, ds) {
            UTL::conf = {.code = code, .sym = symbol("XX", 2)};
        }
        [[eosio::action]]
        void tst() {
            print("\ntst(): code=", UTL::conf.code, ", sym=", UTL::conf.sym);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer, as pointed out by larryk85 on github https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/751 is to properly initialise the static variables.  duh!

```
    class UTL {
        public:
        static name code;
        static symbol sym;
    };  

    name UTL::code = name{};
    symbol UTL::sym = symbol{};
```